# NLog: Log the user who called the application in a WCF application in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, logging, nlog

I have the following scenario:

- A deployed WCF service running as windows hosted service. This WCF service is used to log specific events to a database (NLog v2). This service uses basicHttpBinding.
- A deployed web application (different server) under IIS. The Application pool runs under NETWORK SERVICE credentials. The web application authentication is Windows-integrated (Active Directory credentials).

Whenever I call the WCF from a console application I can get the user identity from `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`; when I call it from the web application I expect to get `"DOMAIN\SERVER$"` as the thread identity name (which occurs as expected).

My problem is: I'd like to get the user who called the web application. I've already tried to set the `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` attribute in the WCF service contract, but the  `${asp-application}`, `${aspnet-user-identity}` and `${asp-request}` parameters in NLog are read as `null`. The `HttpContext` in the web application is OK, but it is not being sent to the WCF. There's a `Credentials` property in the `NLog.Logger` class, but it's read-only.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to set **impersonateCallerForAllOperations** attribute

See MSDN for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731306.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you could get the user from code, you could do this:

```cs
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;

...

// Register ${myUser}, do this as soon as possible (e.g. app_start)
LayoutRenderer.Register("myUser", (logEvent) => someUser);
```

Now you could use `${myUser}` in your nlog config1